# Apache Ignite Heap size recommendation

Tags: kubernetes, ignite

I have a Kubernetes setup of 7 Apache Ignite servers and over 100 clients.

With my current Apache Ignite configuration, I am seeing the following line of log for the servers:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Below is the memory configuration Apache Ignite server:

- Pod memory limit: 2Gb
- Xmx: 768m

I would like to know what should be the optimum Memory configuration for the Apache Ignite cluster

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're trying to do -- persistence and SQL tend to use more heap space for example -- but both 2Gb and 768Mb are *much* smaller than I'd expect for an in-memory database.

The [tuning guide](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/perf-troubleshooting-guide/memory-tuning) suggests 10Gb as a starting point:

```
-server
-Xms10g
-Xmx10g
-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
```

Comment: Well, since Ignite mainly uses Off-Heap, maybe you can tone it down to 4G.

Comment: I am using Apache Ignite as caching server and I have disabled persistence.

Comment: As @alamar says, 10Gb might be on the high side. I would also recommend fewer server nodes but with each node having more memory.